# Using cURL and simpleXMLElement to extract data. How do I get the value of the XML element after XPATH?

Tags: php, html, curl, xpath, simplexml

I am having some problems extracting the data I want from a SimpleXMLElement object. Here is the basics of the code I am using:

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL );
$html = curl_exec( $ch );
$html = $tidy->parseString( $html, $tc, 'utf8' );
$tidy->cleanRepair();
$html = $tidy->body()->value;
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement( $html );

$xml = $xml->xpath( "//ul[@id='wxoptions']/li[3]/a" ); //Your XPATH

print_r( $xml );
```

This navigates to the correct HTML element I want, but prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [href] => http://www.mylink.com
                    [title] => mylink
                )

            [0] => mylink
        )

)
```

The value I need is the [href], "http://www.mylink.com" in that array. How do I extract that from the output I included? I'm stumped and very new to SimpleXMLElement and Xpath.

Comment: Note that you can also select attibute's directly: `//ul[@id='wxoptions']/li[3]/a/@href`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use iterate, and [attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

```
foreach ( $xml->xpath( "//ul[@id='wxoptions']/li[3]/a" ) as $node)
{
  $href = $node->attributes("href");
}
```

Or directly called :

```
$href = $xml[0]->attributes("href");
```

Comment: I tried using both of these approaches:
`$xml = $xml->xpath( "//ul[@id='wxoptions']/li[3]/a" );
$href = $xml[0]->attributes("href");`

But this returns an empty SimpleXMLElement Object to $href.

Comment: Just to clarify, which method you have used ? (The one you mentioned in the comment is a wrong usage)

Comment: Or you can include the example of the XML ?

Comment: You're responses helped me come to a solution. Thanks for you're help.