# Xpath filtering xml results received using curl

Tags: php, xml, curl, xpath

I am trying to filter xml results obtained with cURL. The way i have it set up now, saves the results received from curl_exec function  in a string format  and then puts them in a file then reads them from the file again and tries to process them with XPATH.

However i want to do it without using the file saving part.

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
$url = "urlhere" ; 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$out = curl_exec($ch);
file_put_contents('flickr.xml', $out);

$result = simplexml_load_file('flickr.xml');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('flickr.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->query('//photo');

echo count($nodes);
?>
```

The file flickr.xml looks like this :

```
<rsp stat="ok">
<photos page="1" pages="109" perpage="150" total="16327">
 <photo id="15428573530" owner="96092563@N08" secret="534438318e" server="5609" farm="6" title="Saint Sulpice" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" ownername="Max Sat" dateadded="1414144502" />
 <photo id="15415068638" owner="44752279@N02" secret="7ac6e62756" server="5609" farm="6" title="A new life for the city" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" ownername="Yolanda Miel" dateadded="1414082468" />
 <photo id="15608813752" owner="96092563@N08" secret="82fd0ac671" server="3940" farm="4" title="Le lion de la place Saint Sulpice" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" ownername="Max Sat" dateadded="1414071991" />
 <photo id="15406849058" owner="16948241@N08" secret="d1f66da83f" server="3944" farm="4" title="romancing Champs-Élysées" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" ownername="hannu &amp; hannele" dateadded="1413994013" />
 <photo id="15409289537" owner="24406544@N00" secret="d7b7734fb5" server="5601" farm="6" title="Jardin du Luxembourg - Paris (France)" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" ownername="Meteorry" dateadded="1413985024" />
 <photo id="14978720073" owner="96092563@N08" secret="dfbb5c031b" server="3935" farm="4" title="Alien Queen?" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" ownername="Max Sat" dateadded="1413969753" />
 <photo id="15413315170" owner="96092563@N08" secret="4943975ff3" server="3935" farm="4" title="Séparation - Breakup" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" ownername="Max Sat" dateadded="1413969393" />
 <photo id="14200986212" owner="48242216@N08" secret="d0a40248bc" server="2927" farm="3" title="Europe solidaire - Pham Van Nghia" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" ownername="emmanuelsaussieraffiches" dateadded="1413959936" />
 <photo id="15571431276" owner="31944362@N03" secret="c1e2dddce8" server="3949" farm="4" title="Nord !" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" ownername="Gregouill" dateadded="1413925095" />
 <photo id="15243339218" owner="41583834@N03" secret="14618f8a9e" server="3934" farm="4" title="La Promenade plantée, Paris, France" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" ownername="Grangeburn" dateadded="1413921859" />
 <photo id="15590321451" owner="24406544@N00" secret="60a268be25" server="5608" farm="6" title="Jardin du Luxembourg - Paris (France)" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" ownername="Meteorry" dateadded="1413918288" />
 <photo id="15569308866" owner="32959905@N08" secret="97d462b13f" server="3945" farm="4" title="FIAC 2014 : César" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" ownername="dprezat" dateadded="1413912578" />
</photos>
</rsp>
```

Also the other problem that i have is that the $xpath->query('//photo') xpath query is not retrieving anything. I need to retrieve the ids of all photos. Is there something that i am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Fixed the XPATH issue, with this :

```
 $result = simplexml_load_file("flickr.xml");
 $nodes = $result->xpath('//photo');
 foreach($nodes as $index=>$node)
 {
    echo $node['id'];
    echo '<br />';
 }
```

Comment: Is there a namespace (`xmlns`) involved?

Comment: No, nothing of that sort

Comment: `$result = new SimpleXMLElement($out);` should work AFAIK?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using cURL and simpleXMLElement to extract data. How do I get the value of the XML element after XPATH?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466567/using-curl-and-simplexmlelement-to-extract-data-how-do-i-get-the-value-of-the-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of nodes, you can do it directly with XPath, using `$xp->evaluate`:

```
$result = simplexml_load_file("flickr.xml");
$c = $result->xpath("count(//photo)");
echo "number of photo nodes: $c" . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
number of photo nodes: 12
```

It looks like you've already got how to access the attributes, but here's another method to add to the pot:

```
# gets the attribute "id"
$ids = $xp->evaluate("//photo/@id");
foreach ($ids as $i) {
    echo "id: " . $i->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
id: 15428573530
id: 15415068638
id: 15608813752
id: 15406849058
id: 15409289537
id: 14978720073
id: 15413315170
id: 14200986212
id: 15571431276
id: 15243339218
id: 15590321451
id: 15569308866
```

Answer (score 1):

DOMXpath::query()/evaluate() returns a [DOMNodelist](https://www.php.net/domnodelist), not an array. It implements Traversable, so you can use it with foreach. But it does not implement Countable. You need to use the property $length.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('flickr.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('//photo');

echo $nodes->length;
```

Output:

```
12
```